# SKIA SkCreateWGLContext returns NULL on Remote Session

Tags: chromium, skia

I have a problem with SkCreateWGLContext on Remote Desktop Session:

```
HDC dc = GetDC((HWND)fHWND);
fHGLRC = SkCreateWGLContext(dc, msaaSampleCount,
        kGLPreferCompatibilityProfile_SkWGLContextRequest);
    if (NULL == fHGLRC) {
        return false;
    }
```

This is only failed on remote desktop session.
Is there any workaround or solution for this problem?

Comment: OpenGL and remote desktop don't play well. You can try Google's Chrome Remote Desktop or some VNC server/client with which you may have more luck.